# Error reading cel files. "All the CEL files must be of the same type"

Tags: r, bioconductor

Input:

```
#---> List .cel files

    library(oligo)

    celpath = "C:/Users/Downloads/GSE98640_RAW.zip"
    
    celFiles <- list.celfiles("celpath", full.name = TRUE)
    
    #---> Read .cel files
    data_raw_cel <- read.celfiles(celFiles)
```

Output after data_raw_cel:

```
    All the CEL files must be of the same type.
Error in read.celfiles(celFiles) : 
  checkChipTypes(filenames, verbose, "affymetrix", TRUE) is not TRUE
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this? The cel files aren't reading and I don't get what it means by the CEL files must be of the same type.

The actual CEL files that are listed in the directory are all .cel files, so I'm not sure.

Comment: Include calls to `library` when you use functions not in base R, please (I've edited the question with `library(oligo)`).

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should `unzip the zip file`.
Then check the pattern of the file whether ending with `.CEL` or `.CEL.gz`.

If the extension is with `.gz`. The following will help:

```
affyRaw <- read.celfiles(list.files(pattern = '*CEL.gz', full.names = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer as I've never used the oligoClasses package.

But your celpath seems to point to a file rather than a path. I'd guess that `celFiles` is a 0 length vector. Remove the file name from the path and see what happens.

Also can `read.celfiles` handle zipped files? From the documentation it seems to handle gzip compressed files - but is that what you have?